# TRIGGER on UPDATE to INSERT row if count(*) is 0

Tags: sqlite, triggers

I am trying to create a counter in sqlite3

Column c3 is my counter

What I need is a trigger that will insert a new row if c1 and c2 don't match the update statement.

The setup:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (c1,c2,c3);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1,1,1);
```

My update command:

```
UPDATE t1 SET c3=(SELECT c3 FROM t1 WHERE c1=1 AND c2=1) + 1 WHERE c1=1 AND c2=1;
```

Here is the trigger, what I got but it isn't working:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr1 
BEFORE UPDATE ON t1 
  WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1 WHERE c1=NEW.c1 AND c2=NEW.c2) < 1 
    BEGIN 
      INSERT INTO t1 (c1,c2,c3) VALUES (NEW.c1, NEW.c2, 0); 
    END;
```

Here are some desperate things I tried:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr1 BEFORE UPDATE ON t1 WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1 WHERE c1=1 AND c2=2) < 1 BEGIN INSERT INTO t1 (c1,c2,c3) VALUES (2, 2, 0); END;
CREATE TRIGGER tr2 BEFORE UPDATE ON t1 WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1 WHERE c1=NEW.c1 AND c2=NEW.c2) = 0 BEGIN INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (2, 2, 0); END;
CREATE TRIGGER tr3 AFTER UPDATE ON t1 WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1 WHERE c1=NEW.c1 AND c2=NEW.c2) = 0 BEGIN INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (2, 2, 0); END;
```

Comment: I'd have thought update triggers will only fire if an update is going to take place.  If no row exists to match the selection (c1=1,c2=1) then your where clause isn't going to select any rows to be updated and the trigger won't fire...

Comment: Bear in mind that sqlite triggers run on a *per-row* basis. This implies, at the very least, that each row to update has been identified, and appropriate values selected into `OLD` and `NEW`. But, as you should know, there is *no* row currently in the table, so the trigger will not fire.

Comment: Wouldn't an INSERT OR REPLACE statement be useful here?

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with insert and 2 triggers.

CREATE TABLE t1 (c1,c2,c3);

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr1 BEFORE INSERT ON t1 BEGIN SELECT RAISE(IGNORE) WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1 WHERE c1=NEW.c1 AND c2=NEW.c2) > 0;
END;
CREATE TRIGGER tr2 BEFORE INSERT ON t1 BEGIN UPDATE t1 SET c3=(SELECT c3 FROM t1 WHERE c1=NEW.c1 AND c2=NEW.c2) + 1 WHERE c1=new.c1 AND c2=new.c2;END;
COMMIT;
```

This will insert:

```
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1,1,1);
```

This will update and increment the counter:

```
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1,1,1);
```

If someone could combine these triggers in to one that would be great.